# COTURN server returns error 701 (and "not reachable?") on Trickle ICE

Tags: ubuntu, webrtc, coturn

I have installed COTURN server on my Ubuntu 18.04 using this instruction https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/1175/how-to-create-and-configure-your-own-stun-turn-server-with-coturn-in-ubuntu-18-04. I did everything as it said there. Opened ports 3478 and 5349 on Ubuntu and checked them with telnet. However when I try to test server here https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/ it says:
**The server turn:simyz.com:3478?transport=udp returned an error with code=701:
TURN host lookup received error.** few times.

When I try to test it from firefox it says:

**0.007 1   host    0   udp 4ba8f2a9-6745-4c5f-ab52-2c464f9f6e81.local  56153   126 | 32512 | 255
0.007   1   host    3   tcp 4ba8f2a9-6745-4c5f-ab52-2c464f9f6e81.local  9   125 | 32704 | 255
0.008   2   host    0   udp 4ba8f2a9-6745-4c5f-ab52-2c464f9f6e81.local  56154   126 | 32512 | 254
0.008   2   host    3   tcp 4ba8f2a9-6745-4c5f-ab52-2c464f9f6e81.local  9   125 | 32704 | 254
0.128   Not reachable?**

When I try to use it in my webrtc app the browser console says that TURN server doesn't work. I use this configuration in my javascript:

```
var configuration = {  "iceServers" : [ { url : 'turn:simyz.com:3478', credential : 'siemens81', username : 'superyegorius' }, { "url" : "stun:stun.1.google.com:19302" } ] };
```

Can anyone point me where the error is and why my turn server doesn't work.

Any help appriciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find any fix for this? I'm using `tls-listening-port=443` in `turnserver.conf` and I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Yes. I have reinstalled the coturn server strictly to the instruction described into the articles (links in my question) and then it started to work.

Comment: Update on this topic: Today I tried to install TURN server and faced this problem again. I want to notice that if you install COTURN on the server which is accessible from the internet by "domainname.com" you should connect to COTURN with turn.domainname.com and add a subdomain "turn" into dns for your domain name. I spent half of my day trying to understand why it didnt work:)

Comment: @metadata also check if your COTURN server listens 443 port. If not check path to your certificates and their permissions.